# How can I move my mail from an offline folder to IMAP?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, imap, pop3

I have tried to setup an IMAP account in Outlook 2010. However, by mistake I made it POP and now the inbox folder is empty.

I now have the mails in an offline folder.

How can I move them back to my IMAP account? Drag and drop doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Are you saying you have created a new IMAP account in outlook and cannot drag and drop from Personal Folder to the IMAP folders?  I have done exactly this before.

Comment: I wanted to make an imap account but by mistake I made it pop. So I want to move the inbox folder back, because is empty now(on the server side). I am trying rright click->copy folder now...betweein the two inboxes

Comment: You'll need to create a new IMAP account in Outlook first.  You cannot upload emails to a pop account.

Comment: I have created the same email account as imap. And deleted the pop. But I can see the emails, still

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by seeing the emails.  Once you have the IMAP account created, you should be able to drag and drop the emails from Personal Folders to the IMAP account.  If outlook won't let you do this, then I would install thunderbird, import the emails from outlook then use thunderbird to upload to the IMAP server.

Comment: I deleted the pop account but the pop3 inbox folders is still there. So I can see the mails. I want these mails(the pop3 inbox folder) to be moved to imap inbox folder

Comment: And what happens when you try?

Comment: I reached 95% of thge transfer and said that server closed the connection...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1725/discussion-between-paul-and-peraueb1989)